# Putting input from form into textarea

Tags: html

I want to know how to take the input from a text input and have it placed in a textarea with text added before and after the input for example:

Here's the input and lets say my input is "Watermelon"

```
<form>
 <input type="test" id="foodName">**"Watermelon"**
</form>
```

I want the text thats inside the input placed into a text area and to have text placed before and after the input (the italicized text is the text there before i enter my input):

```
<texarea>
 (foodName)*I think* **"Watermelon"** *is a amazing food!*
</textarea>
```

Answer (score 1):

This is pretty straight forward:
First you have to create a textArea :

```
<textarea id="myArea"> </textarea>
```

Then we will take the value from the text input:
we will use Javascript to take the value and put the value in the textArea:

```
       <script>
function myFunction(){
      var nameOfFood=  document.getElementById("foodName").value;
    document.getElementById("myArea").innerHTML = "I think" + nameOfFood+ "is an amazing food !";
}
    </script>
```

The one thing that you have to be aware is of when to run the javascript code. If you create a button, you can make onClick() call to make input value appear on the textArea.

For button it will be:

```
<button onClick="myFunction">Click me! </button>
```

Now, when the button is clicked, then it will transfer data from the input area to textArea !

Comment: Thank you and what would the code for he button be?

Comment: And also if I were to have many inputs how can I make them print on a new line

Comment: You can simply write </br> to make a new line.